# Extract matrix from existing matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have written a code to generate a matrix with four columns to get all combinations of numbers whose sum is equal to 9 and each number varies from 0 to 9.

```
m = zeros(220, 4);
pd = 9;
i = 1;
for p = 0:1:pd
    for q = 0:1:pd-p
        for a = 0:1:pd-q-p
            m(i,:) = [p, q, a, pd-a-q-p];
            i = i+1;
        end
    end
end
m
```

Now i want filter the arrays with no zero, one zero, two zeros, three zeros. Like,
Three zero case

```
0 0 0 9
```

Two zero case

```
0 0 1 8
0 0 2 7
.
.
0 0 8 1
```

One zero case

```
0 1 1 7
0 1 2 6
.
.
.
0 7 1 1
```

and no zero case

```
1 1 1 6
1 1 2 5
.
.
6 1 1 1
```

and so on..

Any suggestions to do that or any alternative method ?
**Update:**

```
0 0 0 9
0 0 1 8
0 0 2 7
    .
    .
0 0 8 1
0 1 1 7
0 1 2 6
    .
    .
    .
0 7 1 1
1 1 1 6
1 1 2 5
    .
    .
6 1 1 1
```

Any suggestions to get the matrix `m` in the above order?

Comment: I may overlook something - but aren't you producing the matrix in this specific order?

Answer (score 7):

This is the best I can do right now, and I haven't tested it on your entire input matrix

```
m(sum(m == 0, 2) == N, :)
```

should return the rows of `m` which contain `N` 0s.

**EDIT:** following your update, here's a suggestion for the complete code:

```
A = zeros(size(m));
k = 1;
for N = (size(m, 2) - 1):-1:0
    rows = (sum(m == 0, 2) == N);
    idx = k:k + sum(rows) - 1;
    A(idx, :) = m(rows, :);
    k = idx(end) + 1;
end
```

Comment: `@High Performance Mark` Thank you for your quick reply. Can you please see my question update

Comment: @noufal Use a `for` loop and iterate `N` from 3 to 0. How hard can it be?

Comment: @noufal, The code Mark has provided you extracts all rows with N zeros. All you have to do now is do a `for` loop that runs from 3 to 0 ,_i.e_ `for N = 3:-1:0`, and execute this line in each iteration (possibly appending the result to some final matrix, if you wish).

Comment: @noufal I added the code to the answer, for your convenience.

Comment: @noufal oops. I used `tf` before I renamed it to `rows`. Fixed.

Comment: @EitanT In my question I initialized m as m = zeros(220, 4), because I know the size of array is 220 (by trail and error!). Do you know how to find the size for a generalized case ?

Comment: @noufal Computing the number of such combinations is a very specific mathematical problem. What general case are you really talking about?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22927/discussion-between-noufal-and-eitant)

Answer (score 5):

To sort by the number of *leading* zeros in a row, all you need is `sortrows(m)`.

To sort by the total number of zeros in a row, use [High Performance Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14380052/1339280).

Comment: shoelzer I see the logic for interpreting the question the way you did. The given example is a bit misleading. Have a +1 anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following function to get all rows of matrix `A` that have `n` zeros:

```
function rows = nzrows(A, n)
  s = sum(A == 0, 2);
  rows = A(s == n, :);
end
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I came up with:

```
zero_index =[];
one_index =[];
two_index =[];
three_index =[];

for i=1:size(m,1)
    if(sum(m(i,:)==0)==0)
        zero_index = [zero_index    i];
    end
    if(sum(m(i,:)==0)==1)
        one_index = [one_index  i];
    end
    if(sum(m(i,:)==0)==2)
        two_index=  [two_index i];
    end

    if(sum(m(i,:)==0)==3)
        three_index =   [three_index i];
    end

end

m(zero_index,:)
m(one_index,:)
m(two_index,:)
m(three_index,:)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It is generally considered bad practice to use dynamic allocation in MATLAB. More specifically, you're matrices `zero_index`, `one_index` etc... are growing inside the `for` loop. You should preallocate memory for them instead.

Comment: @EitanT In my question I have preallocated, because I know the size of resulting matrix, What to do if we are not certain about the size of matrix?

Comment: @noufal Then over-preallocate and then remove the unnecessary part. In most cases you can at least bound the dimensions of the matrix if you cannot determine its final size.

Comment: @EitanT, Thank you so much. I will take care of it