# Changing variable name in loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix

This is in continuation to my question  [Extract matrix from existing matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379451/extract-matrix-from-existing-matrix)
Now I am separating these matrices by the code ***(Not correct !)***

```
for i = 3:-1:0
    mat = m((sum((m == 0), 2)==i),:)
end
```

**The  above part is an update to my original question**

I want to name it accordingly, like

```
mat1
mat2
mat3
mat4
```

Can anybody suggest an easy method to it?

Comment: In most cases when you need something like that it's better to use `cell`s.

Comment: Learn to use `struct` or `cell` - your approach leads you to writing very bad code.

Answer (score 10):

Following @Jonas and @Clement-J.'s proposals, here is how toy use `cell`s and `struct`s:

```
N = 10; % number of matrices
cell_mat = cell(1, N); % pre allocate (good practice)
for ii = 1 : 10
    cell_mat{ii} = rand( ii ); % generate some matrix for "mat"
    struct_mat.( sprintf( 'mat%d', ii ) ) = rand( ii );
end
```

Nice thing about the struct ([with variable field names](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/13/use-dynamic-field-references/)) is that you can `save` it

save( 'myMatFile.mat', 'struct_mat', '-struct');

and you'll have variables `mat1`,...,`mat10` in the `mat`-file! Cool!

**Some good coding practices:**

1. Pre-allocate matrices and arrays in Matlab. Changing a variable size inside a loop really slows down Matlab.
2. Do not use `i` and `j` as loop variables (or as variables at all) since they are used as `sqrt(-1)` by Matlab.
3. Why having variables with variable names? You need to have an **extremely good** reason for doing this! Please describe what you are trying to achieve, and I'm sure you'll get better and more elegant solutions here...

Comment: I second the opinion that using a structure to aggregate your matrices is a better idea than creating lots of separate variables.  [Here's a link to an article about using dynamic field references](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/13/use-dynamic-field-references/) that would be great for you to read.

Comment: @tmpearce - thanks for the link - I added it into the answer!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to do it using the `eval` and `sprintf` functions. See documentation for both to learn more about them.

```
for count = 1:10
    eval(sprintf('mat%d = zeros(count);',count));
end
```