# Matlab - Giving indexes to vectors

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix

Say that I want to implement the following `while-loop` in `matlab`:

```
n=10;
k=0;
while k<n
    a = 3;
    Cnew = Ck "union" a;
    if (Ck+1==0)
        Ck+1 = Cnew;
    end
end
```

How can I do that, especially the indexing of `vectors`? How can I have the following vectors C1, C2, C3, ...etc in matlab?

Thanks.

Comment: What is it you want to achieve with your loop? I ask because it seems to me that you're headed down a very non-idiomatic, and thus possibly painful route.

Comment: it's really hard to understand your questions: would you mind to be more specific, providing us with inputs and outputs you want, and explaining step-by-step what you want to achieve?

Comment: Could you explain in plain language what you're trying to do? You want to create several new vectors C1, C2, inside the while-loop? And what value do you want to assign? You probably need to use the eval function in Matlab, but without more explanations, I cannot help you more.

Comment: The main thing I just need to understand is how to index vectors. Say for example I reached `k=4` in the loop. How can I write: `Cnew = C4 "union" a`. Union is just simply here adding an element to the vector. But, the important thing as I mentioned is the index of the vector

Comment: I still believe that being less vague would make a huge difference.

Comment: Your example code is an infinite loop as neither `k` nor `n` ever change. It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. Are you trying to to append a new value to the end of a vector?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you don't really want to generate different variable **names** such as `c1`, `c2`, ... etc.

Have you considered using [cell arrays](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html)?

Your code would look something like

```
n=10;
k=1;
C{1} = [];
while k <= n
    a = 3;
    Cnew = [ C{k}, a ];
    if numel(C) < k+1 || isempty( C{k+1} ) % what you meant by Ck+1==0 ?
        C{k+1} = Cnew;
    end
end
```

see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14416582/changing-variable-name-in-loop) for a similar problem.