# Matlab - Indexing variables

Tags: matlab, for-loop, indexing

I asked a similar question to that but the replies were concentrated on indexing by `0` which I just mentioned in the context of the question. Here, I modify the question and don't want zero indexing especially after I knew it may be complex in `matlab`.

My question...

I'm trying to make a `for-loop` in `matlab` that would return the following:

```
C_1 = 0
C_2 = 0
C_3 = 0
C_4 = 0
C_5 = 0
```

I gave it a try as follows but didn't work:

```
function test
for i=1:5
        C{i} = 0
    end
end
```

**EDIT**

This is the output that I get (why is it like that)?

```
C = 

    [0]


C = 

    [0]    [0]


C = 

    [0]    [0]    [0]


C = 

    [0]    [0]    [0]    [0]


C = 

    [0]    [0]    [0]    [0]    [0]
```

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing variable name in loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14416582/changing-variable-name-in-loop)

Comment: you want an array or a cell? Cause from your example looks like a cell.

Comment: Have you deleted the previous question? Why do you make duplicate questions instead of improving existing ones? this behavior spams SO.

Answer (score 0):

From your example, it looks like you want this:

```
[C{1:5,1}] = deal(zeros(1,1));
```

if, instead you want an array, type in

```
C = zeros(5,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get what you see is that in the loop

```
for i=1:5
    C{i} = 0
end
```

you don't terminate the statement with a semicolon. What happens is this:

First time through the loop, the cell array C is initialized with a single element of `0` at position `1`. The result is output because there is no terminating semicolon:

```
C = 

    [0]
```

This shows C is a cell array with a single element - the array `[0]` (everything in Matlab is an array, even a scalar).

After the second pass through the `for` loop, C is a two-cell, array, and its contents are displayed:

```
C = 

    [0]    [0]
```

etc.

If you want the exact output you are describing,

C_1 = 0
C_2 = 0
C_3 = 0
C_4 = 0
C_5 = 0

You would want to create five variables whose name is generated programmatically. The function you can use for this is `assignin`, whose syntax is `assignin(workspace, varname, value)`

The following loop does exactly what you are asking for

```
clear all
for ii=1:5
    assignin('base', sprintf('C_%d', ii), 0);
end
clear ii

whos
```

This will show you have created five variables, `C_1` through `C_5`, with values set to zero.

It should be obvious how to modify this code to something less trivial.

On the whole, you would want to use "regular" arrays wherever practical because of the speed advantage, and cell arrays when the individual elements are different - different types, sizes, etc.  A good use of a cell array is for labels:

```
myLabels={'this', 'that', 'label'};
```

Typically if you need an array of five values that are all zero, the right syntax is almost always

```
myArray = zeros(1, 5);
```

Note - in Matlab, if you write `zeros(5)` it will create a square 5x5 matrix. In some other packages like FreeMat, that produces a 1x5 matrix...